Why does pallet-babe have a `MaxNominators` configuration?
Going through the pallet again for a project and I can see that it has a config item for MaxNominators which unsurprisingly has the following description:

The maximum number of nominators for each validator.

This seems like a polkadot specific, or nPOS consensus specific configuration item, which is why I am confused why it's here. Can someone explain the rationale behind this?
